# Create points from list of X, Y and Z in Dynamo Python Script

Tags: python, autodesk, revit, revitpythonshell

I have 3 lists, each is the X, Y and Z coordinates of the points. I tried using Dynamo's Point.ByCoordinates nodes, however it doesn't accept list as input.

I try to create a Python script to assist me in this, however I'm very new to python, could someone assist me here?

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *
#The inputs to this node will be stored as a list in the IN variables.
dataEnteringNode = IN


a=[]
for i in IN:

a.append(Autodesk.Point.ByCoordinates(IN[0][i],IN[1][i],IN[2][i]))
a # the list with the new items.

#Assign your output to the OUT variable.
OUT = a
```

This is so far what I come out with, but I don't know how to process anymore. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add an example of you input and desired output?
It's not clear what you have exactly and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Sure! Give me a moment

Comment: May be solved here: https://forum.dynamobim.com/t/getting-x-coordinates-alone-from-point-through-python-script/21789/9